# Mysql not connecting using docker

Tags: mysql, docker

Docker image used:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/?tab=description

docker command used:
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_USER=mysqladmin -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=Notallowed1! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql:latest

with root\password
getting this error "Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'"

With "adminuser\Notallowed1!"
Access denied for user 'adminuser'@'192.168.99.1' (using password: YES)

Connection properties:
allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
useSSL=false and true both tried

Answer (score 0):

Hello this seems to be a problem with your MySQL client, not the database itself.

Can you tell us which client you are using?

Have you tried to connect with another SQL client? (PHP/ mariadb-client, DataGrip etc?)

Comment: I used dbeaver https://dbeaver.io/download/

Comment: a quick googling for your software and the issue should tell you what to do: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1042

Comment: Hi @daveforst Thanks you, I checked the link.But there is no solution mentioned here.And the error is also different from the one I got.